# "render Issues" with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am having some render issue while showing the jetpack components. The screenshot is like this

[image]

If I click on the error icon from the screenshot, it shows

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.activity.compose.LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)   
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview   ... (ComposeViewAdapter.kt:528)   
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:124)   
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:583)  
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:580)
```

The composable is something like

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun TestCompose(){
    Column { 
        Text(text = "something")
    }
}
```

Comment: clear rebuild and invalidate catch and restart.

Comment: Welcome, brother. If any queries then ask fell free to.

Comment: I had the same problem without any reason, And it didn't solve ever. My solution was to define a new shortcut key to do faster rebuilds

Answer (score 4):

In my case first I solved by pressing the button `Sync Project with Gradle Files` or `Build & Refresh` (green arrows in a right top corner). But later it didn't help.

[image]

Then I pressed `Render issues`, `View problems`.

[image]

Or yellow exclamation mark:

[image]

Then pressed `Render problems` and found an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having rendering issues while loading an jpeg image, but when i replaced with jpg it works fine !
So, if the your preview rendering is handling an image resource as well make sure that extensions are type jpg/ png.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Iguana and found that I had to just close and reopen the project to get a clean build and resolve the resource.